# Docker exporter does not generate pom.xml file

Tags: docker, integration, wso2-integration-studio

I'm creating an Integation project and request the creation of a dockerExporter, but the folder is created without the pom.xml file.

These are the generated files:
[Pasta DockerExporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzipU.png)

I need the "pom" file to configure my integration

Comment: pom.xml usually is the Project Object Model for Apache Maven. Why should a docker exporter configure that file? Why should a pom.xml be part of a docker image? And what is your 'DockerExporter' anyway?